# How to read a csv in R with backtick as string encoser and ¥‎ as escape character?

Tags: r, csv, fread

I have CSV data with backtick (`)as a string encloser and yen symbol (¥)‎ as an escape character.

Example :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried reading the raw file and replaced yen symbol with a backslash but not working.

```
fl <- readLines("data.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
fl2 <- gsub('¥', "\\", fl)
writeLines(fl2, "Edited_data.txt")
sms_data <- fread("Edited_data.txt", sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "\`", dec = ".", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Expected Dataframe

[image]

Comment: Could you post the desired data frame that you would like to obtain after reading this file in?

Comment: @Konrad I have edited the question and added the expected data frame please check.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't access your data since it's an image but here's a version with `readr`:

```r
library(readr)
dt <- "Sentence, Value1, Value2\n`This is the first row`, 0, 0\n`This , this is something else with a comma¥`, 0, 0"

# We can read for your data, respect your strings within `` and read the the `¥` symbol.
dt_read <- read_csv(dt, quote = "`")
dt_read
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Sentence                                    Value1 Value2
#>   <chr>                                        <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 This is the first row                            0      0
#> 2 This , this is something else with a comma¥      0      0

# Then, we just replace that symbol with nothing
dt_read$Sentence <- gsub("¥", "", dt_read$Sentence)
dt_read
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Sentence                                   Value1 Value2
#>   <chr>                                       <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 This is the first row                           0      0
#> 2 This , this is something else with a comma      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the escape sequence to whatever you like and change it back once you read the text in. I have reproduced your data here:

```r
yen <- c("Sentence,Value1,Value2", 
         "`ML Taper, Triology TM`,0,0", 
         "90481 3TBS/¥`10TRYS/1SR PAUL/JOE,0,0", 
         "`D/3,E/4`,0,0")
writeLines(yen, path.expand("~/yen.csv"))
```

Now the code

```r
library(data.table)

# Read data without specifying encoding to handle ANSI or UTF8 yens
fl <- readLines(path.expand("~/yen.csv"))

# The yen symbol is 0xc2 0xa5 in UTF8, so we want it encoded this way
utf8_yen <- rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xc2, 0xa5)))
ansi_yen <- rawToChar(as.raw(0xa5))
fl <- gsub(utf8_yen, ansi_yen, fl)

# Paste on our backtick to get the backtick escape
yen_tick <- paste0(ansi_yen, "`")

# Change the backtick escape then remove all yen nsymbols
fl2 <- gsub(yen_tick, "&backtick;", fl)
fl2 <- gsub(ansi_yen, "", fl2)

# Save our modified string and reload it as a dataframe
writeLines(fl2, path.expand("~/Edited_data.txt"))
sms_data <- fread(path.expand("~/Edited_data.txt"),
                  sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "\`", dec = ".")

# Now we can unescape our backticks and we're done
sms_data$Sentence <- gsub("&backtick;", "`", sms_data$Sentence)
```

So now we have

```r
sms_data
#>                           Sentence Value1 Value2
#> 1:           ML Taper, Triology TM      0      0
#> 2: 90481 3TBS/`10TRYS/1SR PAUL/JOE      0      0
#> 3:                         D/3,E/4      0      0
```

Comment: Here you are replacing  ¥` with &backtick, but the problem is what if there is ¥% in the sentence. we can't keep on converting each pattern right. so is there any general way to make ¥ as escape line character like \

Comment: You don't need to convert it to an escape once it is in your dataframe; you can just remove it with `gsub("¥", "", sms_data$Sentence)`. You only need to convert the ones that prevent correct reading of your data. I have added this last operation to my answer - test it out.

Comment: your code works but minor change is required, we need to get the yen symbol from ASCII code we shouldn't just copy-paste from some websites if we copy-paste the yen symbol disappears after close and opening of the script
```r
fl <- readLines(path, encoding = "UTF-8")
  # get Yen symbol (escape character in updated data) from ASCII code 165:

  yen <- intToUtf8(165) 
  fl2 <- gsub(paste0(yen, "`"), "&backslash;", fl)
  escape_character_replacement <- gsub(yen, "", fl2)  
  save_data <- writeLines(escape_character_replacement, file_save_path)
```

Comment: The Yen symbol is encoded differently in UTF8 and ANSI. In UTF8 it is encoded by the bytes 0xC2 0xA5, whereas in ANSI it is encoded as 0xA5, so you would need to ensure these are UTF-8 encoded Yens in the document otherwise your code doesn't work. I will update the answer so that it works for both encodings.